# Orchard Multi-Tenancy Setup/Configuration

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am starting to play with Orchard's multi-tenancy options to enable a single codebase to host dozens of websites (perhaps over a hundred in the future). The pieces I'm unclear on with this are:

1. Is it possible to call one or more API endpoints to dynamically create these sites from code on my end? Meaning, we have an existing codebase (non-Orchard) in .Net so what API(s) would I call to create these sites on the fly without having to login and do it manually?
2. In conjunction with #1, are there API(s) for us to create the individual users for the newly created sites that have a pre-configured set of minimal permissions (create content, deal with media, navigation) and blocking others (settings, user management, etc.)? Our client base for this process is not particularly computer savvy so limiting what they can break will go a long way in saving our support staff having to fix stuff they shouldn't be accessing to begin with.
3. Is there a way to handle SSO within these multi-tenant sites? The difficult part here would be our site relies on Session variables for access (it's a hybrid of classic ASP and .Net that I'm trying to modernize, but have to leave things like Session in for all the old stuff to work)? I'm guessing this would get into building a module, but know that's a rather advanced process so I'm trying to avoid it if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, but Orchard doesn't easily integrate into existing applications. dotNest is an example of Orchard sites being created dynamically: http://dotnest.com/knowledge-base/topics/lombiq-hosting-suite
2. Yes. Users can be created from code, and you can assign them restricted permissions, the simplest way of doing it being to create a group with that permission set, and to put those users into that group. All of that can be done from code.
3. Just use oAuth like the rest of the world.
4. Just forget about integrating Orchard into an existing application. Especially classic ASP ;) Time to move on.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. For #3, that's planned for new properties but we're a long way off from supporting that process. There are over 4,000 physical pages spread across thousands of folders - some in use, some not, some "new" ones (i.e. aspx vs. asp) redirect to the asp ones, etc. It's a nightmare. I'm definitely trying to modernize this, but it's a massive project. One last question for this - if I create a new Content Definition in the main installation, how do those get propagated down to the various tenants? Given how many we have now, manual would be a daunting task for new features.

Comment: You'd have to export a recipe (using the metadata export from import/export), and then use that as part of the recipe that creates the new sites. Recipes can also be run from the command line, if you need to do that propagation after the sites have been created.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm going to first dig into module creation for this since I found an example of one late last night that creates content types on the fly. Since I have to now build a module for one thing anyway, I'll just make it all encompassing instead. Thanks again for all the help!